# How to optimise large data ingestion from database by Logstash and reduce ingestion time

Tags: java, postgresql, elasticsearch, optimization, logstash

I am trying to pull data in Logstash from a Postgres DB. The data is monthly, with approximately 140 000 000 records each month. I need to ingest this data in one go and not every 5 few minutes for updates etc or weekly. It's a fresh batch each time.  There are several problems:

1. The ingestion takes too long, 140 000 000 records initially took 48hrs and now takes approx 17hrs
2. The select query pagination takes longer for each subsequent page it ingests. The first page takes 8 secs but by the time we get to 40 000 000 records, it takes 120 secs per page (now) and eventually gets to almost 15 minutes.

How can I optimize this?

I increased the number of workers to match the number of cores of the machine which improved performance significantly. But it is recommended that I should not go above that since it is advised not to and with it running CPU usage is quite high so adding more workers is likely to crash the system. Should I?

I also increased the pagination from 100 000 to 150 000 to 200 000. All with improved times. Much higher numbers crashed the system. I am currently incrementing by 50 000 in my tests but I know I have a limit to this.

I cannot use keyset pagination since I cannot dynamically set a key for each page as logstash runs the query.

I have played with the pipeline batch size increasing to 1250 to 2500 and now 5000 with no noticeable impact on speed/performance. Should I be using much larger amounts?

The machines are dedicated to logstash and we are already using all the ram we can use.

Example Query:

```
input {

  jdbc {

    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/postgresql-42.3.1.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://@host:$port/MYDB"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "password"
    #schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT date_tranc('hour', client_received_timestamp) as client_received_timestamp, is_error, httpsStatusCode from MYSCHEMA.MY_TABLE WHERE client_received_timestamp >= '2023-05-01 00:0:0' AND client_received_timestamp < '2023-06-01 00:0:0' UNION ALL SELECT date_tranc('hour', client_received_timestamp) as client_received_timestamp, is_error, httpsStatusCode from MYSCHEMA.MY_SECOND_TABLE WHERE client_received_timestamp >= '2023-05-01 00:0:0' AND client_received_timestamp < '2023-06-01 00:0:0' UNION ALL SELECT date_tranc('hour', client_received_timestamp) as client_received_timestamp, is_error, httpsStatusCode from MYSCHEMA.MY_THIRD_TABLE WHERE client_received_timestamp >= '2023-05-01 00:0:0' AND client_received_timestamp < '2023-06-01 00:0:0'"
    tracking_column => client_received_timestamp
    clean_run => false
    last_run_metadata_path => "/usr/share/logstash/queues/last_run_update_time"
    jdbc_page_size => 250000
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
  }

}

filter {

  mutate {
    add_field => { "SCHEMA" => "MYSCHEMA" }
    add_field => { "TABLE" => "MY_TABLE" }
  }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts       => ["https://elasticsearch:9200"]
        user        => "user"
        password    => "pass"
        index       => "logs-from-db-v1-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

Pipeline config:

```
- pipeline.id: my-db-pipeline
  path.config: "/etc/path/to/db-v1.config"
  pipeline.workers: 8
  pipeline.batch.size: 5000
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Sound like this issue is with the database no ? My understanding is that the database slows down when you start to paginate the data ?

For elasticsearch you may want to look at esRally, it will allow you to run benchmark and see if you ES cluster is able to handle more incoming data.

Comment: Elastic hasn't had any issue consuming the data. This is about the logstash query with the DB.

Comment: Yes, my first assumption is that the postgres DB is not able to deliver the data faster ...

Comment: "I cannot use keyset pagination since I cannot dynamically set a key for each page as logstash runs the query."  But logstash can run the query with :sql_last_value. Isn't that just what you need?

Comment: You describe this as a one time thing, but your `schedule` setting says otherwise.

Comment: @jjanes the schedule was meant to be commented out. Corrected.  :sql_last_value is only written after the pipeline runs to completion and essentially what you are now consuming is what comes after. In a clean run you do not have a sql_last_valule

Comment: I don't use logstash, but I thought you could get :sql_last_value to be used between pages, not just between schedules, if you set other parameters the right way.

Comment: @jjanes ah, I see. Unfortunately, it does not seem I can set that value between pages. If I could then I could use keyset pagination which would hasten the process significantly

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about crash from higher values of jdbc_page_size, I assume that is a memory issue in the jdbc driver (but you should really investigate the logs to describe what it is that is going on more precisely).  I think that you should be able to avoid the memory issue while keeping the performance improvement by setting jdbc_page_size to a large value while setting jdbc_fetch_size to a smaller (but nonzero) value.